# When using a Custom View - How do I add a Button or other views?

Tags: android

Here I have an Activity that sets a custom view based on a separate class(menuAnimation).

```
package nick.game.breakout;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class GameMenu extends Activity {

    menuAnimation myMenu;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
    myMenu = new menuAnimation(this);

    setContentView(myMenu);  
}
}
```

This is the myMenu View. It simply bounces a ball image around the screen. My issue now is not knowing how to add a button to this view because I want this view to be a simple 2 button menu with the ball bouncing around in the background. I know how to add a button through XML with a content view that uses an xml layout but I am lost when using this custom view.

```
    package nick.game.breakout;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;

public class menuAnimation extends View {

    Bitmap ball;
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    int dx;
    int dy;
    int vx = 5;
    int vy = 5;

    public menuAnimation(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2186ed"));
        ball = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ball);

    }

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    drawBall(dx,dy, canvas);
    dx = dx + vx;
    dy = dy + vy;

    if (dx < 0 || dx > canvas.getWidth() - 10) vx = -vx;
    if (dy < 0 || dy > canvas.getHeight() - 10) vy = -vy;

    invalidate();
}

private void drawBall(int x2, int y2, Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(ball, x2, y2, paint);

}
}
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are setting current view of the page to myMenu using following line.

```
setContentView(myMenu);
```

You will get a view of whatever you have in your myMenu object.

Your myMenu Object extends View object. So Basically myMenu is a view.

You can create a button and add it to myMenu object and it will show a button.

something like

```
Button button = new Button(context); // or use this
myMenu.addView(button);
```

Comment: O right thanks, I was hoping it would be that simple. Is this a complicated way to go about doing this for a simple game menu? Also I get an error when implementing this code.    The method addView(Button) is undefined for the type menuAnimation

Comment: Should the menuAnimation Class be a ViewGroup instead?

Comment: Always try to  XML layout file and add it to setContentView. If I were you I would use XML layout and setContentView with that layout. Layout will already have Button/other views. If It is not possible to add menuAnimation directly into XML layout document then I would use a simple LinearLayout or something in the Layout file and using code in onCreate I will add menuAnimation to LinearLayout view using AddView().